# R: cannot update vctrs package from version 0.1.0 to 0.2.1

Tags: r, github, devtools, vctrs

I'm looking to install the package 'blob' however when I try to do so I get the error message

> "Error in loadNamespace(i, c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[i]]) : 
>      namespace 'vctrs' 0.1.0 is being loaded but >= 0.2.1 is required"

I have tried using both of the following methods to no avail and can't find a solution to get either of them to work

1).    require(devtools)
install_version("vctrs" ,version = "0.2.1")

2).    library(remotes)
install_github("cran/blob")

for method 1). I get the error "Error: compilation failed for package 'vctrs'"
and for method 2). I get the error " cannot open URL 'https://api.github.com/repos/cran/blob/tarball/master'  "

any alternate methods to update the 'vctrs' package, successfully install the 'blob' package or to fix the problems with the above methods would be much appreciated, Thanks!

Comment: Check your R version (R>3.2) and try again or download the package [here](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/vctrs/index.html) and install it via RStudio from your harddisk.